# RSpec Testing for Slack-Ruby-Bot Commands

Tags: ruby, rspec, slack-api

I have been implementing a basic slack bot to a channel and as the code is very simple I have no public methods. Just commands from slack-ruby-bot gem. But as project requirement I need to add several unit testing to my project. Basically when I give command of @ruby_codes strings it gives me the wiki page of that area. how can I test this? attached my version but tests fail everytime.

My command example is as follows:

```
module RubyCodes
  # SlackBot command methods#
  class GetWiki < SlackRubyBot::Commands::Base
    command 'strings' do |client, data, _match|
      client.say(channel: data.channel, text: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Strings')
    end
```

My test case is as follows:

```
describe SlackRubyBot::Commands do
  it 'returns ruby strings wiki page' do
    expect(message: "#{SlackRubyBot.config.user} strings").to respond_with_slack_message('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Strings')
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

also, this is the error I get:

```
expected to receive message with text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Strings once,
        received:[{:text=>"Sorry <@user>, I don't understand that command!", :channel=>"channel"}]
```

Comment: You are passing a hash into `expect`. That wont work. Please post your full code.

Comment: I updated the post to include command cases

Comment: `expect(message: "#{SlackRubyBot.config.user} strings")` this isn't actually calling your method. I am not familiar with this gem, how _do_ you send a message from code normally?

Comment: `command 'strings' do |client, data, _match|
      client.say(channel: data.channel, text: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)#Strings') ` this line actually returns the text whenever I call @ruby_bot strings in channel